# Complete lattice without greatest element

Tags: set-theory, terminology, lattice-orders

Is there any term for "complete lattice without greatest element" (because the lattice is too big to have the greatest element).

A typical example would be the lattice of all small (in Grotendieck's sense) sets. (This lattice does not have a greatest element.)

Comment: If it's made clear that you're talking about large complete lattices, then there's no reason at all to expect a greatest element. I'd be somewhat surprised to find a general term for them, as I don't think order theorists tend to study large objects in their own right and a category theorist would likely be happy to say something about a distributive complete poset lacking a final object.